# What encoding string tells a web server NOT to send gzip content?

Tags: http, header, gzip

This encoding header tells a web server to send gzip content if available.

```
'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
```

How can I instruct the web server to send plain text and not gzip the content?
I am aware that the web server can simply ignore this request if it wanted to.

Comment: this might be just a really naive answer, but shouldn't you just remove the 'gzip' entry from that list of accepted encodings?

Comment: wouldn't that leave to web-server to decide if to gzip or not? I want to explicity say don't send gzip content.

Comment: No. If you don't 'accept' gzip, the server may not send gzip.

Comment: @saeed If it's in the accept-encoding, it's up to the server to decide, if it's not, it's not allowed.

Comment: Can someone get this link to return something other than gzip?  http://regnskaber.virk.dk/83177682/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzL2ZkLzBhL2YxL2RlLzMxOTEtNGEyZi04ZTMyLTVjYTY1MzY0OGQ3Yg.xml Chrome will accept gzip by default. If I try from curl `curl "http://regnskaber.virk.dk/83177682/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzL2ZkLzBhL2YxL2RlLzMxOTEtNGEyZi04ZTMyLTVjYTY1MzY0OGQ3Yg.xml" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Accept-Encoding: deflate, sdch" ` I don't get back the plain XML I expect. Nor if I try `... -H "Accept-Encoding: identity" ...`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Leaving the encoding out of accept-encoding will disallow that encoding (ie gzip).

If you want to *explicitly* set it as disallowed, you can set a `qvalue` of 0.

```
'accept-encoding': 'gzip;q=0,deflate,sdch'
```

You can read more under accept-encoding in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3), but in short if the server can't find an acceptable encoding among the ones listed (identity being a special case, see the link), it should send a 406 (Not Acceptable) response and not reply to your request with any other encoding.

Comment: Leaving out the gzip string did work on the server am working with but qvaule did not. I guess it depends on the server and how its configured.

Comment: The [busybox httpd](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c#n2356) is an example of a server not supporting the qvalue, so for some embedded devices, `gzip;q=0` wont work.

Answer (score 84):

Not including the `accept-encoding` header implies that you may want the default encoding, i.e. `identity`. The caveat here is that the [RFC2616 sec 14.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.3) allows the server to assume any available encoding is acceptable.

To *explicitly* request plain text, set `'accept-encoding: identity'`

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Leaving the encoding out did not help.

Comment: Have you encountered a response with no `content-encoding` headers?

Comment: Will> i had the same issue, and my server replied gzip content if no encoding were specified (the said server was a Tomcat 8). The "identity" encoding solved my pb.

Comment: Tested this myself on `http://ismycomputeron.com`, a website that likes to use gzip/deflate, with telnet, and it works.