# (code 31) where only whitespace is allowed when parsing json from URL with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I get the following error when I try to map the below json response using jackson:

```
Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)):
only regular white space (\r, \n,\t) is allowed between tokens
```

I there any way I can filter out any malformed json before mapping?

```
node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new URL(uri.toString())); <<<<< THROWS THE ERROR
{
    meta: {
        indexAllowed: false
    },
    products: {
        products: [ 
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Apple iPhone 6 16GB 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Apple iPhone 7 8GB 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Catching exception is not an option?

Comment: @MartinJimmyHlavňa: How would that help. The exception causes the parsing to stop.

Comment: If you have malformed json you cannot parse it.

Comment: @MartinJimmyHlavňa: Well, you can. You just need to write your own "MyMalformedJson-Parser" :-).