# Spring Feign Not Compressing Response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I am using spring feign to compress request and response

**On Server Side:**

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/v1/
  compression:
    enabled: true
    min-response-size: 1024
```

When I hit the api from chrome, I see that it adds `'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br"`

**On Client Side:**

```
    server:
      port: 8192
      servlet:
        context-path: /api/demo



feign.compression.response.enabled: true

feign.client.config.default.loggerLevel: HEADERS

logging.level.com.example.feigndemo.ManagementApiService: DEBUG

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false

management-api:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080
```

When I see the request headers passed, feign is passing two headers.

```
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

**gradle file**

```
plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }

    group = 'com.example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    ext {
        set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR2")
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        compile ('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon')
        compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-httpclient
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-httpclient
        //compile group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-httpclient', version: '9.5.0'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }
```

The response is not compressed. What I have seen is that Spring feign is sending the "Accept-Encoding" as two different values

Let me know if thing is wrong here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have faced the same issue a couple of weeks back and I came to know that there is no fruitful/straight forward way of doing it. I have also got to know that when @patan reported the issue with the spring community [@patan reported issue1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/216) and [@patan reported issue2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18176) there was a ticket created for the tomcat side to attempt to fix the issue ([issue link](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63737)). There has been also a ticket ([ticket link](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/pull/4066)) present in the Jetty side related to the same. Initially, I planned to use the approach suggested in [github](https://github.com/jmnarloch/feign-encoding-spring-cloud-starter) but later came to know that the library had been already merged into `spring-cloud-openfeign-core` jar under `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.encoding` package. Nevertheless, we could not achieve compression as expected and faced the following two challenges:

1. When we enable the feign compression by settings the `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.encoding.FeignAcceptGzipEncodingInterceptor` ([code-link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/1e1562b24a77d9da2b19b8132d296a145d33b98a/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/encoding/FeignAcceptGzipEncodingInterceptor.java#L47)) class adds the `Accept-Encoding` header with values as `gzip` and `deflate` but due to the issue ([ticket](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63737)) the tomcat server could not interpret it as a sign of compression signal.  As a solution, we have to add the manual Feign interpreter to override the
   `FeignAcceptGzipEncodingInterceptor` functionality and concatenate the headers.
2. The default compression settings for Feign perfectly work in the most simple scenarios but when there is a situation when `Client calling microservice and that microservice calling another microservice through feign` then the feign cannot handle the compressed response because Spring cloud open feign decoder does not decompress response by default ([default spring open feign decoder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/1e1562b24a77d9da2b19b8132d296a145d33b98a/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/FeignClientsConfiguration.java#L78)) which eventually ends with the issue ([issue link](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/934)). So we have to write our own decoder to achieve decompression.

I have finally found a solution based on various **available resources** so just follow the steps for the spring feign compression:

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  http:
    encoding:
      enabled: true

#to enable server side compression
server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types:
      - application/json
    min-response-size: 2048

#to enable feign side request/response compression
feign:
  httpclient:
    enabled: true
  compression:
    request:
      enabled: true
      mime-types:
        - application/json
      min-request-size: 2048
    response:
      enabled: true
```

**NOTE**: The above feign configuration my default enables compression to all feign clients.

**CustomFeignDecoder**

```
import feign.Response;
import feign.Util;
import feign.codec.Decoder;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.encoding.HttpEncoding;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class CustomGZIPResponseDecoder implements Decoder {

    final Decoder delegate;

    public CustomGZIPResponseDecoder(Decoder delegate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(delegate, "Decoder must not be null. ");
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
        Collection<String> values = response.headers().get(HttpEncoding.CONTENT_ENCODING_HEADER);
        if(Objects.nonNull(values) && !values.isEmpty() && values.contains(HttpEncoding.GZIP_ENCODING)){
            byte[] compressed = Util.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream());
            if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
               return delegate.decode(response, type);
            }
            //decompression part
            //after decompress we are delegating the decompressed response to default 
            //decoder
            if (isCompressed(compressed)) {
                final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
                final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line);
                }
                Response uncompressedResponse = response.toBuilder().body(output.toString().getBytes()).build();
                return delegate.decode(uncompressedResponse, type);
            }else{
                return delegate.decode(response, type);
            }
        }else{
            return delegate.decode(response, type);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isCompressed(final byte[] compressed) {
        return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
    }
}
```

**FeignCustomConfiguration**

```
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CustomFeignConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    //concatenating headers because of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18176
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor gzipInterceptor() {
        return new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
                template.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomGZIPResponseDecoder customGZIPResponseDecoder() {
        OptionalDecoder feignDecoder = new OptionalDecoder(new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(this.messageConverters)));
        return new CustomGZIPResponseDecoder(feignDecoder);
    }
}
```

**Additional tips**

if you are planning to build the CustomDecoder with just `feign-core` libraries

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import feign.Response;
import feign.Util;
import feign.codec.DecodeException;
import feign.codec.Decoder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.lang.reflect.WildcardType;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import static java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC;

public class CustomGZIPResponseDecoder implements Decoder {

    private final Decoder delegate;

    public CustomGZIPResponseDecoder(Decoder delegate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(delegate, "Decoder must not be null. ");
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
        Collection<String> values = response.headers().get("Content-Encoding");
        if (Objects.nonNull(values) && !values.isEmpty() && values.contains("gzip")) {
            byte[] compressed = Util.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream());
            if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
                return delegate.decode(response, type);
            }
            if (isCompressed(compressed)) {
                Response uncompressedResponse = getDecompressedResponse(response, compressed);
                return getObject(type, uncompressedResponse);
            } else {
                return getObject(type, response);
            }
        } else {
            return getObject(type, response);
        }
    }

    private Object getObject(Type type, Response response) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        if (response.status() == 404 || response.status() == 204)
            return Util.emptyValueOf(type);
        if (Objects.isNull(response.body()))
            return null;
        if (byte[].class.equals(type))
            return Util.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream());
        if (isParameterizeHttpEntity(type)) {
            type = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            if (type instanceof Class || type instanceof ParameterizedType
                    || type instanceof WildcardType) {
                @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
                HttpMessageConverterExtractor<?> extractor = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor(
                        type, Collections.singletonList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper)));
                Object decodedObject = extractor.extractData(new FeignResponseAdapter(response));
                return createResponse(decodedObject, response);
            }
            throw new DecodeException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
                    "type is not an instance of Class or ParameterizedType: " + type);
        } else if (isHttpEntity(type)) {
            return delegate.decode(response, type);
        } else if (String.class.equals(type)) {
            String responseValue = Util.toString(response.body().asReader());
            return StringUtils.isEmpty(responseValue) ? Util.emptyValueOf(type) : responseValue;
        } else {
            String s = Util.toString(response.body().asReader());
            JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type);
            return !StringUtils.isEmpty(s) ? mapper.readValue(s, javaType) : Util.emptyValueOf(type);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isCompressed(final byte[] compressed) {
        return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
    }

    public static Response getDecompressedResponse(Response response, byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
        return response.toBuilder().body(output.toString().getBytes()).build();
    }

    public static String getDecompressedResponseAsString(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    private boolean isParameterizeHttpEntity(Type type) {
        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            return isHttpEntity(((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType());
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isHttpEntity(Type type) {
        if (type instanceof Class) {
            Class c = (Class) type;
            return HttpEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(c);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private <T> ResponseEntity<T> createResponse(Object instance, Response response) {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        for (String key : response.headers().keySet()) {
            headers.put(key, new LinkedList<>(response.headers().get(key)));
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>((T) instance, headers, HttpStatus.valueOf(response
                .status()));
    }

    private class FeignResponseAdapter implements ClientHttpResponse {

        private final Response response;

        private FeignResponseAdapter(Response response) {
            this.response = response;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpStatus getStatusCode() throws IOException {
            return HttpStatus.valueOf(this.response.status());
        }

        @Override
        public int getRawStatusCode() throws IOException {
            return this.response.status();
        }

        @Override
        public String getStatusText() throws IOException {
            return this.response.reason();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            try {
                this.response.body().close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Ignore exception on close...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
            return this.response.body().asInputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
            return getHttpHeaders(this.response.headers());
        }

        private HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders(Map<String, Collection<String>> headers) {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                httpHeaders.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
            }
            return httpHeaders;
        }
    }

}
```

and if you are planning to build your own Feign builder then you can configure like below

```
 Feign.builder().decoder(new CustomGZIPResponseDecoder(new feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder(new feign.codec.StringDecoder())))
                 .target(SomeFeignClient.class, "someurl");
```

**Update to the above answer:**
If you are planning to update the dependency version of `spring-cloud-openfeign-core` to `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:2.2.5.RELEASE'` then aware of the following Change in [FeignContentGzipEncodingAutoConfiguration class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/commit/bf13ae95c954f0f5001278d4b607e54527d35b71).
In `FeignContentGzipEncodingAutoConfiguration` class the Signature of the `ConditionalOnProperty` annotation changed from
`@ConditionalOnProperty("feign.compression.request.enabled", matchIfMissing = false)` to `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "feign.compression.request.enabled")`, so by default `FeignContentGzipEncodingInterceptor` bean will be injected into spring container if you have application property `feign.request.compression=true` in your environment and compress request body if default/configured size limit exceeds. This results a problem if your server don't have a mechanism to handle the compressed request, in such cases add/modify the property as `feign.request.compression=false`

Comment: Thanx alot, this is the ultimate solution I have found after hours of searching. The proplem I had was : 

feign.codec.DecodeException 
...
...
JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an exception in Tomcat and Jetty - multiple encoding headers as given above is legal and should work, however Tomcat and Jetty have a bug that is preventing them to both be read.

The bug has been reported in the spring boot github [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18176). 
And in tomcat [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63737) for reference.

In Tomcat the issue is fixed in `9.0.25` so if you can update to that, that can solve it. Failing that, here is a workaround you can do to fix it:

You will need to create your own request interceptor to reconcile your gzip, deflate headers into a single header.

This interceptor needs to be added to the FeignClient configuration, and that configuration added to your feign client.

```
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import feign.template.HeaderTemplate;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

/**
 * This is a workaround interceptor based on a known bug in Tomcat and Jetty where
 * the requests are unable to perform gzip compression if the headers are in collection format.
 * This is fixed in tomcat 9.0.25 - once we reach this version we can remove this class
 */
@Slf4j
public class GzipRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        // don't add encoding to all requests - only to the ones with the incorrect header format
        if (requestHasDualEncodingHeaders(template)) {
            replaceTemplateHeader(template, "Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip,deflate"));
        }
    }

    private boolean requestHasDualEncodingHeaders(RequestTemplate template) {
        return template.headers().get("Accept-Encoding").contains("deflate")
                && template.headers().get("Accept-Encoding").contains("gzip");
    }

    /** Because request template is immutable, we have to do some workarounds to get to the headers */
    private void replaceTemplateHeader(RequestTemplate template, String key, Collection<String> value) {
        try {
            Field headerField = RequestTemplate.class.getDeclaredField("headers");
            headerField.setAccessible(true);
            ((Map)headerField.get(template)).remove(key);
            HeaderTemplate newEncodingHeaderTemplate = HeaderTemplate.create(key, value);
            ((Map)headerField.get(template)).put(key, newEncodingHeaderTemplate);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception when trying to access the field [headers] via reflection");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception when trying to get properties from the template headers");
        }
    }
}
```

I know the above looks overkill, but because the template headers are `unmodifiable`, we just use a bit of reflection to modify them to how we want.

Add the above interceptor to your configuration bean

```
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FeignGzipEncodingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor gzipRequestInterceptor() {

        return new GzipRequestInterceptor();
    }
}
```

You can finally add this to your feign client with the configuration annotation parameter

```
@FeignClient(name = "feign-client", configuration = FeignGzipEncodingConfiguration.class)
public interface FeignClient {
    ...
}
```

The request interceptor should now be hit when you send a feign-client request for gzipped information. This will wipe the dual header, and write in an acceptable string concatenated one in the form of `gzip,deflate`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest spring boot version then it provides default Gzip decoder so no need to write your custom decoder. Use the below property instead:-

```
feign:
  compression:
    response:
      enabled: true
      useGzipDecoder: true
```

Comment: I tried this, but have no luck, not sure if it is related to my version of spring-boot,
Anyway, the answer of @Prasanth_Rajendran is working perfectly.