# Spring Boot Web - How to remove chunked transfer-encoding in the response header

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gzip

How do I disable the transfer-encoding `chunked` in a spring boot web app (2.7.1) or latest version?

I already have these properties.

```
server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    min-response-size: 1024
    mime-types: application/json
```

I also send the `Accept-encoding` header as `gzip`.

Even though I see the `gzip` in the response header, I do not think that it is really compressed (with or w/o gzip, the response size is same with 150 KB). I also do NOT want transfer encoding chunked.

[image]

---

UPDATE: I have another webflux application which works great. I do not see chunked. gzip works just great. This is not anything to do with postman.

- when I do not send the accept-encoding header

[image]

- for the same request, when I send the accept-encoding header
  [image]

Comment: Why do you think that the response isn't really compressed? The headers suggest otherwise. Depending on the client you're using, it may be unzipping the response body before showing it to you. Also, the transfer encoding has to be chunked as the content length is unknown when gzipping a response.

Comment: I have used gzip in other apps 150KB is reduced to 10 KB. this app still shows 150KB. also as the response is chunked -  it is not even gzipping i believe.

Comment: What is the request asking for in `accept-encoding` header? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046671/2834978

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot seems to be from `Postman`, which shows decompressed size and not the compressed size.

Here's a screenshot from `Postman` for my `Gzip` enabled REST service

[image: Order service Postman Response]

1. `Content-Encoding` is telling client that it content transferred was `gzip` compressed. It may be incorrect, if you're just setting this header without compressing the response content. However, since you're relying on Spring to do this, it's most likely correct and response is compressed.
2. `Transfer-Encoding` just means that response may be sent into multiple HTTP packets. This is done when server does not know the size of response content in advance, before it starts writing to `ServletOutputStream`. Server can know the size of response content in two ways. First is to buffer serialized response into memory and then get it's byte array length. Second one is to discard serialized content while calculating the size. In the second scenario, server will have to serialize the response twice, once to find size and once to write to `ServletOutputStream`. As you can see that both of these methods to find response size in advance are not desirable. **Server will set this `Transfer-Encoding` to chunk, even when your response is not Gzipped**. That's because JSON serialization in **Spring is handled in such a way to allow response to be written to `ServletOutputStream` as soon as any part of JSON becomes available in the buffer. This way server can serve first byte faster.** **It will happen even for the smallest response**. Having `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` doesn't mean that your response is not compressed. What it means is that Gzip bytes are written to `ServletOutputStream` as soon as they become available
3. Postman shows decompressed size only. You can see actual transferred size and decompressed size in Google Chrome separately.

[image: Chrome shows network transfer size and decompressed size separately]

Alternatively you can see both sizes using `CURL` commands

[image: Using curl to see compressed and uncompressed sizes separately]

Here are the commands in text

```
#Find uncompressed size
curl -so target/test.json localhost:8080/order -w "%{size_download}"

#Find compressed size
curl --compressed -so target/test.json localhost:8080/order -w "%{size_download}"
```

Comment: This is not anything to do with postman. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Have you verified that the first `curl` command above returns full size with `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response. As I explained `Transfer-Encoding` has nothing to do with response being compressed or not. At this point, unless you post a minimal working example to demonstrate the issue, it'll be very difficult for anyone to answer your question.